# Deducing the relation $f(x)-f(x+1)+f(x+2)-\cdots = 0.5f(x)+Af'(x)+Bf''(x)+\cdots$ from Abel's "Studies on Elliptic Functions"

Tags: sequences-and-series, elliptic-functions

In Abel's famous article "Studies on Elliptic Functions", most of which I've understood, there is a formula that confused me.
It is like this:
$$f(x)-f(x+1)+f(x+2)-\cdots = 0.5f(x)+Af'(x)+Bf''(x)+\cdots$$

Abel said this is a known equation, but I don't know how to deduce it.
For $A, B$, he just said "where $A, B, ...$ are numbers", nothing else.

If I use Taylor expansion for the left part on $x=x$, we can get:

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=f(x) \\[4pt]
f(x+1)&=f(x)+f'(x)\cdot1+\frac{1}{2!}f''(x)\cdot 1^2+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(x)\cdot1^3+\cdots\\[4pt]
f(x+2)&=f(x)+f'(x)\cdot2+\frac{1}{2!}f''(x)\cdot 2^2+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(x)\cdot2^3+\cdots\\[4pt]
\cdots&=\cdots\\[4pt]
f(x+k)&=f(x)+f'(x)\cdot k+\frac{1}{2!}f''(x)\cdot k^2+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(x)\cdot k^3+\cdots
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
f(x)-f(x+1)+f(x+2)-f(x+3)+ \cdots &= 
(1-1+1-1+\cdots)f(x) \\[4pt]
&+(-1+2-3+\cdots)f'(x) \\[4pt]
&+\frac12(-1^2+2^2-3^2+\cdots)f''(x)\\[4pt]
&+\frac{1}{6}(-1^3+2^3-3^3+\cdots)f'''(x)\\[4pt]
&+\cdots
\end{align}$$

So refer to Abel's equation, we can see:
$$\begin{align}
1-1+1-1+\cdots&=0.5 \\
-1+2-3+\cdots&=A \\
-1^2+2^2-3^2+\cdots&=B
\end{align}$$
This is strange because the left series are divergent.

so I just want to know how this equation is deduced.

In the original article, the function $f(x)$ is $$f(m,x)=\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-((m+\frac{1}{2})w+(x+\frac{1}{2})w'\sqrt{-1})^2}$$ $\alpha,m,w,w'$ can be seen as real constants.

This question is important for Abel's deduction and to have a good understanding of elliptic functions, as I haven't seen anything similar in the textbook, this technique may be used in other research. In fact, in his article, there are many print mistakes, it is $Bf'''(x)$ in the original article.

However, by the meaning of Abel, it seems that the equation doesn't depend on the concrete form of f(x). Because he used this equation as a known equation as he said.

If you are still not clear, https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/1/abeltranslation.pdf

Download this paper and at the end of page 64, you can find it, this part is self-contained and doesn't depend too much on the context.

Comment: What does $f$ represent?

Comment: We should all be able to spell [Niels Hendrik Abel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Henrik_Abel)'s name properly.

Comment: @C-RAM  there is a expression of f, but I think this formula do not depend on f.

Comment: I have shown my thinking on this question, I don't know why nobody can answer it.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @caijiu: I made some formatting improvements, and I gave your question a better title. Perhaps this will attract answerers. I'm also voting to reopen, as this seems like a reasonable question. Good luck!

Comment: @5xum   I am angry! Why don't you ask Abel? You ask me? I am not Abel, in his article, he said A,B are numbers, just this.

Comment: @caijiu I don't have the article. I have your question. Your question, which, by the rules of this site, should be self contained. Currently, your question does not contain enough information to answer it because $A$ and $B$ are unknown. You being angry does nothing to change this, and you acting like a petulant child will only alienate people making it less likely that they will be willing to help you.

Comment: @5xum  why can't me a child? and in Abel's , he just said A,B are numbers, this is all he said as I have told you.

Comment: In Abel's original article, there are some print mistakes, in the original paper, it is B^3f'''(x), not B^f''(x), I can't diff whether it is a mistake,  and some others, but I think this doesn't affect the understanding of this question.

Comment: @caijiu This is a site for users to help other users. The people helping gain *nothing*, and do so because they want and like to do it. Very few people will *want* to help a user that is angry and that reacts to genuine questions with answers full of angry entitlement. So, sure, you *can* act as a child if you want. Just don't expect people to come running to help you.

Comment: @5xum   why don't you focus on the question? I think I have answered your question. A,B are numbers. Don't tell me great truth, I don't think people can't act as a child if they like, not to mention they are.

Comment: @Blue   I am curious why you can edit my question.

Comment: @caijiu "they are numbers" is not a sufficient answer. Without knowing their value, the right hand side of your equation is not well defined, and therefore, the validity of the equation cannot be verified.

Comment: @5xum    This is all Abel said, I can understand you don't have enough talent to answer this question.  But I can tell you, Abel just means that there exist numbers A, B, ... to make this equation hold.  Even I can understand his meanings.

Comment: @caijiu: *"I am curious why you can edit my question."* That's how the site works. A certain reputation level earns the ability to edit questions to help improve their quality. For your question, tidying-up the equations improves readability. Also, making titles as specific as possible tends to get more attention; conversely, vague titles tend to be ignored (and they can frustrate future site searchers). ... Anyway, if you don't like the edits someone else makes, you're always free to roll the question back to its previous state. ... Good luck to you!

Comment: @caijiu: By the way ... Please try to make your question as self-contained as possible. I think you've done pretty well here in walking through your own thought process. But comments are asking for the original context of the formula, and suggesting that people to Google for the article isn't helpful in that regard. (A good rule of thumb: *Treat the reader's time as more important than your own.* This is especially true when you're asking the reader for assistance.) Posting a screenshot of the relevant passage(s) —or links to them— is the better way to go. ... Cheers!

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your advice, god bless you.

Comment: Look up Euler-Maclaurin formula, which associates sums over $f$ with a properly designed sum over higher order derivatives of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation about the history and under the help of Wiki, I found a good explanation of this question at last.
By the famous formula:
$$1-2^n+3^n-4^n+... = \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}B_{n+1}$$
We can use it to calculate and get your desired result.